# Searchable FAQ on a Sharepoint

Tags: search, sharepoint

I created a FAQ page on the MS Sharepoint.
I want to group the questions into some sections.
Is there any possibility to make this page searchable and add a "search" box? So that user can type in a keyword and find related question/answer.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POiJ1.png)

There is no "search box" in the "Add a new web part" list.

Answer (score 0):

You would need custom code.

The easiest way to do what you want is to add headings to each FAQ and then add a bunch of buttons at the top of your page which link to the headings.

There are multiple pre-built FAQ apps you can use though..

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-faqapp

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-doccard-faq

https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-accordion-dynamic-section

Or you can use PNP Modern Search, I built some FAQ's using that.